# Groovy String To Date

Tags: groovy, soapui, simpledateformat

I am trying to parse a String using the SimpleDateFormat, but the resulting Date seems to be off by a few months (day of the week, time (different time zone) and year are correct).

```
def headers = messageExchange.getResponseHeaders() 
def String dateHeader = headers.get("Date",null)

log.info "DATE:" + dateHeader

SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("[EEE, dd MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss zzz]")
Date c = dateFormat.parse(dateHeader)

log.info c
```

OUTPUT:

```
DATE:[Thu, 08 Nov 2012 14:08:22 GMT]
INFO: Thu Jan 05 15:08:22 CET 2012
```

All ideas are welcome!

Comment: Works here in Groovy 1.8.4... (using yyyy instead of YYYY)

Comment: thx a lot, that was the problem =) cannot reward/accept your comment though...

Comment: I thought I had 80 more rep than I actually do. You are far ahead. signed: PBI ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date format should use 'y' instead of 'Y' for the year.